# Is there any way to make horses unable to jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a horse track in Minecraft, but I don't want people to be able to jump over the starting gate at the beginning. I tried using `/effect @e 8 1000000 150`, which made me unable to jump but made the horses jump really high. How can I make it so that they can't jump either?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a negative value of jump boost effect to achieve a corrupted jump boost (which, in effect, makes an entity unable to jump). You can't use the `/effect` command to do this, though, you have to edit the entity data manually. Which can be done like so:

```
/entitydata @e[type=EntityHorse] {ActiveEffects:[{Id:8,Amplifier:-128,Duration:600,Ambient:0}]}
```

Where `Duration` is measured in ticks. So 600 ticks will give you around 30 seconds of no jumping. Adjust this value depending on what you want. This is the best solution if you want just a temporary "no jump" effect.

If you want this to be permanent, that can be done too. Horses also have a `horse.jumpStrength` attribute in their NBT data. If you want to make all horses unable to jump, you can change that value to '0' with the following command:

```
/entitydata @e[type=EntityHorse] {Attributes:[{Name:"horse.jumpStrength",Base:0}]}
```

This will make all horses completely unable to jump. You can reset this by setting the value to some other value, however, that will set the overall jump strength for all horses to be the same, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I learned quite a few things from this post, and I didn't even ask the question.

Comment: this is a very good answer thanks, it works very well

Comment: There should be a way to save the original value to a scoreboard objective for each horse.  How you would go about resetting each horse with a single command is beyond me though.

Comment: @MBraedley Sure, you can do that, but you wouldn't be able to set entity data with that, reasonably. It'd get really messy with something to the effect of `/entitydata @e[type=EntityHorse,score_jump=0.7,score_jump_min=0.69] ...` for each small increment of jump range. Although I'm actually not sure how you would set the score in the first place anyway. Using negative jump boost is the much simpler way to accomplish it.

Comment: Oh, it isn't even stored as an int?  That complicates things.  I don't even know if scoreboard objectives can even hold floating point numbers.

Comment: @MBraedley They cannot, actually. The internal score NBT tag is a TAG_int.

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer: Make an arch over the starting gate so that the horses can't jump over.

Comment: they might be able to jump over the fences and cheat

Comment: except that I specifically said to make the arch so they can't jump over. As in, make it low enough that a horse can't pass between the top of the fence and the arch. Like most starting gates in real life...
Not sure whether you're working in survival or not, but it really bugs me when people turn to command blocks to accomplish something that would easily be solved by a bit of creativity instead.

Comment: yeah i dont know whhat your meaning